# TSQL turning these multiple CASE queries into one query

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have the following CASE queries that return 1 if they find anything, and 0 otherwise. I would like to turn these into a single query that returns 1 if any of them are true, or 0 otherwise. How can I acomplish this?

```
SELECT CASE WHEN count(PLACE.CODE) > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
FROM PLACE
WHERE STYLE = 'RED'
AND RULES = 'NO'



SELECT CASE WHEN count(GARDEN.AREA) > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
FROM GARDEN
WHERE PLACE = 'GROUND'
AND MAZE = '1'


SELECT CASE WHEN count(place_area.AVAILABLE_AREA) > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
FROM PLACE_AREA as place_area
INNER JOIN USED_PLACE as used_place
    ON used_place.COLOR = 'RED'
    AND used_place.MAKE = 'INDUSTRY'
WHERE place_area.CODE = 'FLOOR'
AND place_area.DANCE = '0'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you can `union all` the result and calculate the `sum`, if `sum > 0` then there was at least one `1`

```
Select Case When Sum(x.col) > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END from
(
SELECT CASE WHEN count(PLACE.CODE) > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as col
FROM PLACE
WHERE STYLE = 'RED'
AND RULES = 'NO'

Union All


SELECT CASE WHEN count(GARDEN.AREA) > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as col
FROM GARDEN
WHERE PLACE = 'GROUND'
AND MAZE = '1'

Union All

SELECT CASE WHEN count(place_area.AVAILABLE_AREA) > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as col
FROM PLACE_AREA as place_area
INNER JOIN USED_PLACE as used_place
    ON used_place.COLOR = 'RED'
    AND used_place.MAKE = 'INDUSTRY'
WHERE place_area.CODE = 'FLOOR'
AND place_area.DANCE = '0'
) x
```

Comment: I am getting `Invalid column name, 'col'`

Comment: and pay attention to `as col` at end of your Case-When statement

Comment: ahh, missed that. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT 
CASE 
    WHEN 
            EXISTS(
                SELECT TOP 1 1
                FROM PLACE
                WHERE STYLE = 'RED'
                AND RULES = 'NO'
                AND count(PLACE.CODE) > 0
            ) 
            OR EXISTS (
                SELECT TOP 1 1 
                FROM GARDEN
                WHERE PLACE = 'GROUND'
                AND MAZE = '1'
                AND count(GARDEN.AREA) > 0
            )
            OR EXISTS (
                SELECT TOP 1 1
                FROM PLACE_AREA as place_area
                INNER JOIN USED_PLACE as used_place
                    ON used_place.COLOR = 'RED'
                    AND used_place.MAKE = 'INDUSTRY'
                WHERE place_area.CODE = 'FLOOR'
                AND place_area.DANCE = '0'
                AND count(place_area.AVAILABLE_AREA) > 0
                ) 
    THEN 1 
    ELSE 0
END
```